# transform list inside a dataframe to rows spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

my dataframe looks like :

```
StationID | Extlist | Situation
5         | 3,2   | Situation_1
```

the formats are strings. 
I would like to transform it to split the "x,y" into lines like this ;

```
StationID | Extlist | Situation
5         | 3       | Situation_1
5         | 2       | Situation_1
```

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `split` then `explode` the column, as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (5, "3,2", "Situation_1"),
  (6, "4,3,2", "Situation_2")
).toDF("StationID", "Extlist", "Situation")

df.withColumn("Extlist", explode(split($"Extlist", ","))).
  show
// +---------+-------+-----------+
// |StationID|Extlist|  Situation|
// +---------+-------+-----------+
// |        5|      3|Situation_1|
// |        5|      2|Situation_1|
// |        6|      4|Situation_2|
// |        6|      3|Situation_2|
// |        6|      2|Situation_2|
// +---------+-------+-----------+
```